# Switch between AWS Beanstalk accounts through the command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm trying to deploy my application through AWS Beanstalk service. I have one environment setup for staging in account A and a different production environment in Account B. Is there a way to switch between the different environments?

When I run `git aws.push`, git updates the most recently created environment. Is there a way to specify which environment to update? I noticed that that there are different .conf files for each environment but only one for aws in the project root. I tried switching the values manually in the shared file but now I seem to have broken eb :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further googling, I found that you can configure your command line tools to use different credentials. [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) has more information on it.

When running commands, aws looks for your credentials in a few different places, which allows a user to setup different aws accounts